# C++, Accept lowercase and uppercase letters in a variable

Tags: c++, variables, function, character-encoding

I want to allow the user to use lowercase or uppercase letters giving the value to the char type variable...  Any help??

Comment: Your question is a bit vague - can you please explain it more clearly?  Do you want to accept characters from the user and then compare it against a string, ignoring the case?

Comment: You are going to need to specify more precisely what you are after. You might be trying to read lines of input from cin and then zapping all non-alphabetic characters before echoing the line. Or you might be trying to convert the case of the letters, or something else.  Or you might be trying to process single characters at a time (since a 'char type variable' can only hold one character at a time).  And what are you going to do with invalid characters?  Ignore, whinge, terminate silently?

Comment: You list C++ as your primary language - you have to be aware that the values of variables don't care about upper/lower case. Please clarify your question, or it will be downvoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Err, do you mean something like (where `getAChar()` is whatever method you're using to get the character):

```
int ch = getAChar();
while (!isalpha (ch))
    ch = getAChar();
```

Alternatively, if you want to check that a user enters only alphas. You can get a string with:

```
cin >> myString;
```

Checking for alphas is as simple as:

```
char *cstr = myString.c_str();
for (int i = 0; i < myString.length(); i++)
    if (!isalpha (*cstr++))
        return false;
return true;
```